# Output multiple .csv files appending the .csv file name as the source folder name with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, server, scripting

I have 30 folders. Each folder contains 22 .text files. I am trying to get the filenames and row count of each .text files and output it in a .csv file, appending the name of the .csv file with the name of each subfolder.

The script I made works but it will pull all the .text files from all subfolders and output it in a single .csv file.

Any idea how I can create one .csv file per subfolder ?

```
$results = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\testserver\Documents\logfiles\*.txt" -Recurse | % { $_ | select name, @{n="lines";e={get-content $_ | measure-object -line | select -expa lines } } } | Select-Object name, lines

$results | Export-Csv "C:\Users\testserver\Documents\results.csv" -notype
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet to process the files grouped by the directory they reside in:

```
$inDir = 'C:\Users\testserver\Documents\logfiles'
$outDir = 'C:\Users\testserver\Documents'

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.txt $inDir |
  Group-Object DirectoryName | 
    ForEach-Object {
      $outFile = Join-Path $outDir "results-$(Split-Path -Leaf $_.Name).csv"
      $_.Group |
        Select-Object Name, @{ n="Lines"; e={ (Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -Line).lines } } |
          Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $outFile
    }
```

The above creates output files such as `results-foo.csv` in `$outDir`, where `foo` is the name of a subdirectory containing `*.txt` files.

Note that the assumption is that no two subdirectories in the target `$inDir` directory tree have the same name; more work is needed if you need to handle such collisions, such as reflecting the *relative paths* in the file name, with `\` replaced with a substitute char.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never thought of using Group-Object !

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TitanL0rd. While it is no speed demon, `Group-Object` comes in handy in many situations.